# Why isn't List view repeating List<String> in wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

When I debug List says, indirect list not instantiated. But I get it fetched lazy in JPA. It is not rendering in Listview but it should have nodes on it. Am I missing something?

```
//.....code......
private ListView<String> reqs; // Requirements
private Label lblreqs;  //Label for repeat requirements
//...code...
    final LigaBaseball lbb = LigaBBServ.buscarPorID(Integer
            .parseInt(idLiga)); //Get Baseball league from database

    if (lbb == null || pageParameters == null
            || pageParameters.get("idLiga") == null)
        throw new RestartResponseException(VerLigas.class); //If null redirect.
//...code...

    add(reqs = new ListView<String>("reqs", new ListModel<String>(lbb.getRequisitos()))//LAZYly get List from LigaBaseball(BaseballLeague) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
        /*When I debug item is null
*/
            item.add(lblreqs = new Label("lblreqs", (item.getModelObject())));
        }
    });

//...code...
```

Comment: can you delete the unimportant parts?

Comment: Do you mean the imports?

Comment: strip your code to consist of only the lines which are directly coherent to your problem. further more try writing your code in english only, it is difficult to put code in context as we dont understand what your code means

Comment: Sorry for the language. Now is edited.

Comment: I would check what lbb.getRequisitos() gets you. Without knowing more, we can 't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... according to this (rather minimalist) UnitTest created from your posted code, it does, but maybe I'm missing the point...

```
package net.unbewaff;

public class DemoTestCase {

    private WicketTester tester = new WicketTester();
    private Panel panel = new MyPanel("panel");

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        tester.startComponentInPage(panel);
        tester.assertComponent("panel", Panel.class);
        tester.assertComponent("panel:reqs", ListView.class);
        tester.assertComponent("panel:reqs:0", ListItem.class);
        tester.assertLabel("panel:reqs:0:lblreqs", "1");
        tester.assertComponent("panel:reqs:1", ListItem.class);
        tester.assertLabel("panel:reqs:1:lblreqs", "2");
        tester.assertComponent("panel:reqs:2", ListItem.class);
        tester.assertLabel("panel:reqs:2:lblreqs", "3");
        tester.assertComponent("panel:reqs:3", ListItem.class);
        tester.assertLabel("panel:reqs:3:lblreqs", "4");
    }

    private final class MyPanel extends Panel {

        private MyPanel(String id) {
            super(id);
        }

        public void onInitialize() {
            ListView<String> reqs;

            final LigaBaseball lbb = new LigaBaseball();

            reqs = new ListView<String>("reqs", new ListModel<String>(lbb.getRequisitos())) {

                protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> item) {
                    item.add(new Label("lblreqs", (item.getModelObject())));
                }
            };

            add(reqs);

            super.onInitialize();
        }
    }

    class LigaBaseball {

        public List<String> getRequisitos() {
            String[] a = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
            return Arrays.asList(a);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Test set: net.unbewaff.DemoTestCase

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.032 sec

Comment: posted this as an answer, because it's to long for a comment.

Comment: I had 2 bugs, The edit page was setting the list to another entity because an code error. Second, the markup was hiding the results. I was using divs and were z-indexed behind other elements, I use a table and now it's ok.